# Label not updating in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have asked a very similar question I believe 2 days ago and it got closed as a mod told me to look at other similar questions but none of the solutions worked. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the error. Here is the code at the moment all it does is print and display the first number in the sequence:

```
import tkinter as tk
#import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold")
window.geometry("300x300")
timer = int(input("time in seconds "))

def update():
  global timer
  timer -= 1
  print(timer)
  hello = tk.Label(window, textvariable = timer)
  hello.pack()
for i in range(timer):
  window.after(1000, update)
  tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- it is not recommended to use console `input()` in a GUI application
- the for loop will be blocked by `tk.mainloop()` until the root window is closed.  However the next iteration will raise exception since the root window is destroyed. Actually the for loop is not necessary.

Below is a modified example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello World")
window.geometry("300x300")

# it is not recommended to use console input() in a GUI app
#timer = int(input("time in seconds: "))
timer = 10  # use sample input value

def update(timer=timer):
    hello['text'] = timer
    if timer > 0:
        # schedule to run update() again one second later
        hello.after(1000, update, timer-1)

# create label once and update its text inside update()
hello = tk.Label(window)
hello.pack()

update() # start the after loop

# should run mainloop() only once
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
#import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold")
window.geometry("300x300")
timer = int(input("time in seconds "))
hello = tk.Label(window, text= timer)
hello.pack()
def update():
  global timer
  timer -= 1
  print(timer)
  hello.config(text=timer)

for i in range(timer):
  window.after(1000, update)
tk.mainloop()
```

something like this should work

Comment: Did you try your solution yourself?

Comment: I have used this one before. so should work here.

Comment: No it does not work as I have tried your solution.

Comment: Try now sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No it still does not work.  The issue is that `after()` is used in a wrong way and `tk.mainloop()` should not be called inside the for loop.  Actually the for loop should not be used.

Comment: you are right @acw1668

Comment: As I said the for loop should not be used.  *Please test your code before posting it as an answer*.

Comment: but it does update atleast for once the question had the code which didn't update anything at all. and he said label not updating in tkinter.

Comment: This answew isn't going to do what you think it does. All of the calls to `after` will happen in rapid succession one after the other, since they will all be queued up about 1000 ms after the loop starts (ie: first time through the loop it's queued up in one second, the second time through the loop will _also_ be queued up in about one second -- not one second after the first one).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Add `cnt= 0` and remove `text=timer`.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Countdown Timer")
window.geometry("300x300")

cnt = 0 
timer = int(input("time in seconds "))
#var = tk.StringVar()
def update(cnt):     
    if cnt > 0:
        window.after(1000, update, cnt-1)
        print(cnt)
    hello['text'] = cnt 

hello = tk.Label(window)
#hello['text'] = timer 
hello.pack()
 
update(timer)  
tk.mainloop()
```